# Best practice to keep linux updated and clean

Tags: upgrade, updates, alias

I got lost with old forum and stuff so here I ask, I did a alias to keep linux updated and clean and I wonder if I did it correctly or if I missed something.

```
alias update='sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade && sudo apt -y autoremove && sudo apt clean'
```

Comment: If you ask me you haven't missed anything - I do basically the same as you. However, I've flagged this question as "opinion based", since I believe this is the case for such a broad question.

Comment: Yes, if you do that, you get the newest updates. Usually security updates get installed automatically anyway, if you don't mess with it. This much for the "updated". For the "clean", well that's another story. Depends on what you mean by that, but that'll be a matter of your personal disciplin, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping your system "updated and clean" is more a set of good habits than any particular shell incantation.

1. Let Unattended Upgrades do it's job. It checks daily for security upgrades and automatically installs them without pestering you. As part of the daily routine, it runs `apt update`.
2. Run `apt upgrade` periodically. Maybe weekly, maybe monthly, maybe whenever the system pesters you. You don't need to do it daily (then you're simply doing Unattended Upgrades' job)...but you're also not hurting anything by doing it daily.
3. Don't build a Frankensystem: Keep your PPAs and non-Ubuntu sources to a minimum. There's a lot of bad advice out there pushing you to adopt the latest-and-greatest by using PPAs and non-Ubuntu repositories.

   Avoid trying to upgrade to the latest-and-greatest application on top of an older LTS release; doing so is a common cause of breakage. If you want newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu -- that's how Debian-based systems are designed to work.
4. Stick to a few packaging systems that you understand. In Ubuntu, that generally means debs and snaps. For advanced users, that might also include pips. You generally don't need to stack AppImages and Flatpaks and Brews on top of those merely because that's what some blogger suggested. Take the extra moment to look for the software in one of your currently-used packaging systems.

   Corollary: How you uninstall software depends upon how you installed it. So you must keep track of your various install methods. Another reason to stick to the defaults when possible.
5. Uninstall software that you're not using anymore. If it's free and in the Ubuntu repositories, then you can get it back at any time. Don't be a software hoarder.
6. Before doing a release-upgrade to the next release of Ubuntu:

   - Backup your data
   - Make a new install LiveUSB...in case something goes wrong.
   - Uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu software, and disable all non-Ubuntu sources. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.
   - Never accept a "partial upgrade." That means you failed the previous step.
   - After a successful release-upgrade, check to see if you still need (or want) that non-Ubuntu source anymore. Maybe the version you want is available from Ubuntu sources now.
7. Keep notes and backups. You should be able to use your notes to rebuild your entire system from scratch, to install all the applications you need, and to add any customizations that you depend upon. Most folks should really only need to backup their (irreplaceable) data. Know how to restore your data from the backup.
8. Read your output. If the system tells you something unexpected, there's probably a pretty good reason. Many warnings and error messages are in plain language.

   Monthly (or so), review part of your /var/log/syslog file. It should be full of boring news about such-and-such login or such-and-such cronjob or that a USB stick was inserted. If it's full of errors and warnings instead, that's your cue to start researching the problem and take action.
9. Use a calendar. Mark your calendar for your weekly/monthly `apt upgrade`. Mark your calendar to remind you to check syslog. Mark your calendar for your next release-upgrade. DON'T let your system run past the end of Community Support and security upgrades. That can be painful to fix.

Answer (score -1):

by searching I found this:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade -y

sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt autoclean

sudo apt clean
```

Comment: Autoclean and Clean don't do much anymore, and you can just do `dist-upgrade` in place of full-upgrade and upgrade, it does the same thing.  You could also just install `unattended-upgrades` and configure it to do this stuff all automatically behind the scenes once a day or so.

Comment: Running `upgrade` *after* `full-upgrade` is pointless. The `-y` flag is unwise -- it disables a key protection intended keep you from destroying your system. `clean` promptly deletes all the work of `autoclean`

Comment: @ThomasWard well, the main reason is I try to create a 'perfect' alias using the command above (not all of them if its not necessary) then create a script using CRON. I know I can use tool like, bleachbit etc. but I want to learn the basic before using tools.

Comment: @ThomasWard @user535733 in summary should I go with something like 

```sudo apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade -y; apt-get autoremove; apt-get autoclean```